# Determine all ways the integer $2015$ can be written as a sum of consecutive positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, summation

> Q) Determine all ways the integer $2015$ can be written as a sum of
>   (more than one) consecutive positive integers. Prove that you have
>   found all possible combinations.

I was thinking of using Gauss' formula where

Sum=$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ Since we want the sum to be $2015$ then $2015=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and then we are left with $4030=n(n+1)=n^2+n$

but then I got stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Rewrite it as $n^2+n-4030=0$ and solve this as a quadratic equation in the variable $n$. Actually  you should aslo try sum of consecutive integers from some $a$ to $b$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/139852/589.

Comment: Well, you don't necessarily have to start from 1 , so $2015= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is not very helpful. Instead , try smaller cases, especially the numbers with odd factors ,and you might spot  something helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  Your thought is a good one, but Gauss' formula presumes you start adding from $1$.  If you add from $m$ through $n$, the sum is $\frac {n(n+1)}2-\frac{(m-1)m}2$  because you subtract the sum from $1$ through $m-1$.  You should be able to factor this.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of an arithmetic progression is the number of terms times the average element.

IF the number of terms is **odd**, then the average element is an integer, so you should look to write 2015 as as a product where the first factor is odd (which is not much of a demand since there can't be an even factor of 2015).

If the number of terms is **even** (and the step size is 1), then the average element is a half-integer, so you should look to write 4030 as a product where the first factor is even and the second is odd.

In each of these cases find out which factorizations lead to the *first* element of the progression being positive.

Comment: If the number of terms are odd then would I be allowed to start at 1 since 1 is a factor.

Comment: @swandilaon: It is the number of terms times the _average term_, not the number of terms times the _first_ term. Starting at 1 is "allowed" as far as it goes, though it won't give you a sum of 2015.