# What is the maximum possible value of $k$ for which $2013$ can be written as a sum of $k$ consecutive positive integers?

Tags: number-theory, summation

What is the maximum possible value of $k$ for which $2013$ can be written
as a sum of $k$ consecutive positive integers?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571604/determine-all-ways-the-integer-2015-can-be-written-as-a-sum-of-consecutive-pos?rq=1) helps you.

Comment: You need only to find out the minimum possible positive integer $m$ for which $s = 4m^2 - 4m + ((4 \times 4026) + 1) = (2m-1)^2 + (4 \times 4026) $ is a perfect square. Then the maximum possible value of $k$ is given by $$\frac {{\sqrt s} - (2m - 1)} {2}.$$

Comment: So it reveals that $m = 3$ will do the job for you and for this value of $m$ we have $\sqrt s = 127.$ So the maximum possible value of $k$ is given by $\frac {127 - 5} {2} = \frac {122} {2} = 61.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The sum of $m$ consecutive positive integers is given by $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$. So what you want is to find the highest value of $k$ for which exist a natural number $m$ so that $$2013=\frac{(m+k)(m+k+1)}{2}-\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$$ holds.

---

I think meanwhile you found an answer by yourself. This is why I now give a full answer to this for all who are asking this or a similar question in future:

> The equation above is equivalent to $$4026=k(k+2m+1)=k^2+2km+k.$$ By the first representation you see that $k$ has to be a divisor of $4026$. All divisors of $4026$ are given by (you can either calculate it by yourself or use W|A)$$1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 22, 33, 61, 66, 122, 183, 366, 671, 1342, 2013, 4026. $$ By the second representation you see that $k^2<4026$ holds. Thus the largest candidate for $k$ is $61$ (as $66^2>4026$). So we now check for this candidate if there exists such a natural number $m$. By solving the equation above with $k=61$ we get $m=2\in\Bbb N$. Since we were only looking for the largest possible value of $k$ we are done.