# An olympiad question

Tags: contest-math

I came across a question ( mentioned below ) which is from a Mathematical Olympiad.

It says,

If $m $ and $n $ are positive integers such that

> $n + (n + 1) + (n + 2) +...+ (n + m) = 1000 $

then how many $(m, n)$ pairs exists ?

[image]

Comment: Do you not understand what the questions is asking or do you not know how to solve it? If it is the first, please make that more clear. If it's the second, what attempts have you made?

Comment: And you've been a member of this site for almost 20 months and you've asked some 13 questions. You should really try to translate the question into english and write it down.

Comment: As a way to get started:  Note that the expression on the left is the difference of two triangular numbers.  Triangular numbers have a simple expression.

Comment: @DonAntonio The OP could have asked at the end "Answer desired in English and in Turkish" :-)

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you have your difficulties?

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/139842/11619).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n(m+1)+(1+2+\cdots+m)=1000$

$n(m+1)+\dfrac 12m(m+1)=1000$

$(m+1)(2n+m)=2000$

Note that $m+1$ and $m+2n$ are of opposite parities. We have to factorize $2000$ into the product of an odd and an even number.
Note that both factors should be greater than $1$ as $m$ is positive.

$2000=5\times400=25\times80=125\times16$

Note also that $m+1<2n+m$.

So, $(m+1,2n+m)=(5,400)$ or $(25,80)$ or $(16,125)$

$(m,n)=(4,198)$ or $(24, 28)$ or $(15,55)$.

Comment: For completeness, you forgot $1\times 2000$ or forgot to state that of course the factors must be $>1$