# Question related to natural numbers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How many ways are there to express a natural number N as a sum of two or more consecutive natural numbers?

How do I count the no. of ways, they don't seem to follow any pattern.

Comment: Write $N=x+x+1$ find $x$. Hint: it's not always possible, especially for even numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In how many ways can a number be expressed as a sum of consecutive numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139842/in-how-many-ways-can-a-number-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-consecutive-numbers)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).