# How Many Natural Numbers Can Get Expressed as the Sum of Consecutive Natural Numbers in only One Way?

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that all even integers $n \neq 2^k$ are expressible as a sum of consecutive positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59131/prove-that-all-even-integers-n-neq-2k-are-expressible-as-a-sum-of-consecutiv)

Some natural numbers can be expressed as a sum of consecutive natural numbers in more than one way.  For example, $7$ can get expressed both as $7$, and $(3+4).$  In terms of a sum of consecutive numbers, $4$ and $8$ can only get expressed as $4$, and $8$ respectively.  Call such numbers consecutive-primes.  How many consecutive-primes exist?  Given all previous consecutive-primes, is there a way to compute the next consecutive-prime?

Comment: The powers of $2$ are the only ones. The problem has been solved on this site, probably repeatedly. [Here is a link.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59131/prove-that-all-even-integers-n-neq-2k-are-expressible-as-a-sum-of-consecutiv)

Answer (score 7):

Only powers of 2 [have exactly 1 odd divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/139852/1284).

Comment: Huh?  What do you mean by "odd divisor"?  I mean, 3 only has one  divisor (discounting 1), which is odd, if by "odd divisor" you mean a divisor which is odd.  Also, how does the notion of "divisor" end up relating here?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Can you see how to use an odd divisor to create a sum of consecutive numbers? Hint: 3=0+1+2