Are the sets of trapezoidal numbers and powers of $2$ complements of each other?
I define a trapezoidal number to be a positive integer that is the sum of at least $2$ consecutive positive integers. I have been tinkering around with this definition, and have come up with the conjecture that the only positive integers which are not trapezoidal are precisely the powers of $2$: $1,2,4,8,16$, etc. I have verified the conjecture for up to the number $16$, but of course what is needed is a proof. Note, a proof has to prove both directions of the implication, both that every power of $2$ is non-trapezoidal, and that every non-power-of-2 is a trapezoidal number.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/59162/472818
